# If I have a function $f(x)$, can I represent it as $f(x, 2x)$ in 3 dimensional space?

Tags: calculus

If I have a function $f(x)$, can I represent it as $f(x, 2x)$ in 3 dimensional space? how to compute the integral of $f(x, 2x)$?

For example, if my $f(x)=3x$, I can also write it as $f(x, 2x) = x+(2x)$, How should I visualize $f(x, 2x)$ in 3 dimentional space? And how should I integrate this functiom?

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful not to give the same name to two obviously different things (a function $f$ of one variable and another function whose input is two variables).

But otherwise the answer is **yes, but there is no canonical way to do that.**

You could go with $$g(x,y)=f(y-x)$$ which is what you suggest yourself do in the question.

You could go with the simpler $$g(x,y)=f(x)$$

You could go with anything of the form $$g(x,y)=f(ax+by)$$ assuming that $x=ax+2bx$ for all $x$, that is $2b+a-1=0$.

As for the integral, your question is not specific enough to be answered but at the end of the day, the integral of something that is a function of $x$ doesn't depende on the expression you use to compute it (no matter over which domain you integrate).